# Basic Deployment of remixjs app using SSR with Nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

After hours of web searching I'm finding it very difficult to gain an understanding of how I should deploy my remixjs app. I'm simply trying to deploy my remixjs app onto a Digital Ocean Dropplet that will also use nginx as a reverse-proxy.

Here's what I understand so far:

- I need Nginx as a reverse proxy to serve content over HTTPS which was already setup using let's encrypt and works good for serving static content.
- I have a Remixjs app that I build using `remix build` and I know from the remix documentation, *"This command will set process.env.NODE_ENV to production and minify the output for deployment."*
- The result is two directories `/build/` and `/public/build/` and from the docs: *"only the build artifacts (build/, public/build/) need to be deployed to production"*
- From my understanding, if I was just serving static content I could use just nginx and just copy over the folder that includes `index.html`. But I think since my content is dynamic, that's why I have `index.js` instead which doesn't work with nginx.
- So I need to deploy another server then route the requests from nginx to that server.
- I don't know how to setup a server so I want to use the remix app server. From the docs: *"Remix is designed for you to own your server, but if you don't want to set one up you can use the Remix App Server instead. It's a production-ready, but basic Node.js server built with Express."*
- Now here is where I'm stuck. My gut is telling me to copy over the two build directories then run `remix-serve build` but that doesn't seem to work and I can't run `npm install` without the package.json but I feel like everything I need to should be self-contained in the build files.

So my question essentially boils down to how do I run `remix-serve build` to use the Remix App Server on my remote machine using the two build artifact folders? or is it necessary to clone the entire project onto the remote machine then build and run? It seems like the correct way would be to utilize the two build artifact folders, but it's not clear to be how I can do that.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much want to create a shell script that executes from a systemd service. I encapsulated my npm install, build, and express server start into a shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/bin/npm i
sudo /var/www/node_modules/.bin/remix build
sudo /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/bin/node /var/www/server.mjs
```

My service file

```
[Unit]
Description=Express server for remix project

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash /var/www/script.sh
Restart=always
RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Once you enable the service it will run the remix server continuously as needed

```
● express-server.service - Express server for remix project
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/express-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since UTC; 1h 2min ago
   Main PID: 102437 (bash)
      Tasks: 17 (limit: 516)
     Memory: 36.1M
        CPU: 3.190s
     CGroup: /system.slice/express-server.service
             ├─102437 /bin/bash /var/www/patient/script.sh
             ├─102440 sudo /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/bin/node /var/www/server.mjs
             └─102441 /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v21.1.0/bin/node /var/www/server.mjs
```

Answer (score 1):

I copy `build`, `public/build`, `package.json` to a folder like `my-remix-deploy` on my remote machine, run `npm install` under `my-remix-deploy` folder, then start it by `npx remix-serve build/index.js &> /dev/null &`. Btw, I use `npx create-remix@latest --template remix-run/remix/templates/remix` to create my project.